# Ошибка Java class JPdfDocument could not be found на Android устройстве

Tags: android, delphi

Взял пример создания Pdf файла на ANDROID устройстве отсюда: https://github.com/FMXExpress/Firemonkey/blob/master/Winsoft/CreateAndroidPDF/Main.pas 
Компиляция на FMX Delphi Tokyo и создание apk файла проходит без ошибок. Нажатие на кнопку на ANDROID устройстве и вызывает эту ошибку.

Comment: имеется возможность отладить приложение и привести StackTrace  и сообщение об ошибке?

Answer (score 1):

Этот класс требует API level 19 или выше

Comment: А откуда у вас уверенность, что у вопрошающего устаревший API?